# Convert html string to pptx in java

Tags: java, html, powerpoint

In my application, there are notes being fed by user inside browser. These notes can be formatted for font, size, color etc. These notes are saved in database using html tags string.

Now I want to export these formatted text into PPTX. Is there any solution for it? Currently, I have tried Apache POI which allows for formatted text but does not allow input of html string.

I am looking for open source library, so using Aspose is a difficulty. Somehow, I need to render these HTML text and then copy as it is to PPTX.

Any solution or way will be helpful.

EDIT: I am thinking for custom parsing the string html text; using JAXB to convert the tags into objects and then using some java logic to integrate POI with it. Any wayout/ help on achieving this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Aspose.Slides offers you to import HTML text inside presentation and also exporting presentation to HTML. I suggest you please visit the following documentation link to serve the purpose in this regard. You are right that Aspose.Slide
I work as developer evangelist at Aspose.

Comment: Unfortunately, Aspose is not available in our workplace. I am looking for open source alternative. However, I will give a shot at Aspose for my personal experience. But currently, I need something different